# .NET MVC Null Object which initialized in constructor of ViewModel using RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two controllers(controllerA.actionA & controllerB.actionB) which share the same view & ViewModel(ViewModel_Shared).

So, in both Controller, I use RedirectToAction to redirect to a third controller(controllerC.actionC) which points to the shared view.
All three Actions are in different Controller.
When ActionA or ActionB was invoked All the parameters that post from view was sent to the modelC in actionC successfully.

However, when I try to feed data into the object(Item), NullReference exception was thrown. the object(Item) was NULL.

But I'm sure the constructor of ViewModel_Shared was hit TWICE while ActionA was called and ActionC was called.

So, basically, object(Item) was NEW twice.

I don't really understand why it's like that.
thank you all in advance!!!

```
public ActionResult actionA (ViewModel_Shared modelA)
{
        return RedirectToAction("actionC", "controllerC", modelA);
}

public ActionResult actionB (ViewModel_Shared modelB)
{
        return RedirectToAction("actionC", "controllerC", modelB);
}

public ActionResult actionC (ViewModel_Shared modelC)
{
        modelC.FillEditedData();

        // Send the data to view
        ViewData.Model = modelC;
        return View();
}

public class ViewModel_Shared
{
    public ItemCustomer Item { get; set; }

    public ViewModel_Shared()
    {
        Item = new ItemCustomer();
    }

    public void FillEditedData()
    {
        // NullReference exception was throw here, somehow, Item is null.
        Item.LegalCost = "some value";
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ItemCustomer
{
    public string Item_No { get; set; }
    public string MaterialPricingGroup { get; set; }
    public string MaterialGroup { get; set; }
    public string Plant { get; set; }
    public string LegalCost { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass an object that contain complex properties using `RedirectToAction` - look at the query string it generates - its `...&Item=yourAssembly.ItemCustomer&...`.

Comment: `RedirectToAction` can only pass scalar values as query string - it can't pass complex objects/properties. You may require AJAX with POST method to pass complex viewmodel object as JSON array instead of redirection which uses GET method.

Comment: Thank you all!!!
I didn't know that the RedirectToAction function will pass the parameters with query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, complex objects cannot travel with requests.

Instead you need to serialize the object and pass the serialized data to the destination action method:

```
public ActionResult actionA (ViewModel_Shared modelA)
{
        var serializedModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelA);
        return RedirectToAction("actionC", "controllerC", serializedModel);
}
```

## UPDATE

My bad. Indeed the parameters, sent through `RedirectToAction()` are sent as route values so even serialization cannot help here. At least not by itself - the routing must be setup appropriately ...

A different approach must be taken and during `actionA`, place your `modelA` into the `TempData`, then do redirect. In the `actionC` retrieve the model and carry on.

```
public ActionResult actionA (ViewModel_Shared modelA)
{
        TempData["shared_model"] = modelA;
        return RedirectToAction("actionC", "controllerC");
}
```

Later, in `actionC`:

```
public ActionResult actionC (ViewModel_Shared modelA)
{
        var modelC = TempData["shared_model"];
        modelC.FillEditedData();

        ViewBag.Model = modelC;

        return View();
}
```

Do note, that the objects in he `TempData` are alive only to the next request and then gone. Here you can read more about the [`TempData`](http://www.gregshackles.com/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/).

Comment: Yes...If I pass the serialized model, ActionC gets Object(Item). However, it losses all other values of other properties somehow.

Comment: I also realize that, in the View of actionA, I can call Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/ControllerC/actionC.cshtml", Model); So that, I can also pass the model to another controller!

Answer (score 0):

Yin

1) if you are using the **ItemCustomer**  class as a property you should initialize it when you are using.

```
public ItemCustomer Item { get; set; }
```

2) if you are using **ItemCustomer** as object it will initialize when you constructor call as your example.

```
public ItemCustomer Item;
```

I have run the second point without get and set it's working fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out! I've tried and it works fine as you said. However, I don't quit understand the why it's designed like this. I thought it's quite good to initialize all the complex object properties in the constructor first to avoid potentially complications.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question - which is about passing a model in a `RedirectToAction()`!